# Where can I find the Legend of Korra save files?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

I'm referring to [this](http://store.steampowered.com/app/281690/) game. I've looked everywhere, and can't seem to find the save file. Google was no much help either, with various resources about games and save files, but with this game or just the save file location of this game missing.

Does anyone know where can I find the save files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/281690/discussions/0/613939841463043222/) post in the steam discussions, the saves are located:

one for save and one for settings (gamedata and systemdata)

C:\Users\username\Documents\Korra

Comment: I tried, I renamed both files in that directory, and nothing seemed to have been erased. The game just created 2 new files, and my save was not removed.

Comment: Are you sure that your game isn't loading from the Steam Cloud? It may be creating a copy of the save file on your computer that matches the save file in the Steam Cloud.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha As ChaseC said, check your Steam cloud settings. (Library>GameTitle>Right-click>Properties>Updates>Bottom checkbox) and then try mucking about with the save files.

Comment: I will try and report back, I don't have the PC with the game readily on my right now :P

Answer (score 0):

These are the save file locations:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Korra\GameData.dat`
- Steam Play (Linux): `<Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/281690/pfx/`

If you can't find it on windows:

- Open the File Explore
- Paste `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Korra\GameData.dat`
- Press Enter